# Dealing with listening socket by epoll

Tags: c, sockets, epoll

All below is from `man epoll` page:

> The function do_use_fd() uses the new 
>   ready  file  descriptor
>          until  EAGAIN is returned by either read(2) or write(2).

Code example for **ET triggered** :

```
   for(;;) {
       nfds = epoll_wait(kdpfd, events, maxevents, -1);

       for(n = 0; n < nfds; ++n) {
           if(events[n].data.fd == listener) {
               client = accept(listener, (struct sockaddr *) &local,
                               &addrlen);
               if(client < 0){
                   perror("accept");
                   continue;
               }
               setnonblocking(client);
               ev.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET;
               ev.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET;
               ev.data.fd = client;
               if (epoll_ctl(kdpfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, client, &ev) < 0) {
                   fprintf(stderr, "epoll set insertion error: fd=%d\n",
                           client);
                   return -1;
               }
           }
           else
               do_use_fd(events[n].data.fd);
       }
   }
```

So for `read/write` operation,we should do it by looping until a `EAGAIN` is received;but why it's not the case for `accept`?

IMO the above code will miss some requests when there're multiple client sockets waiting to be accepted, as it accepts only **1** client socket, we should also wrap it in a loop until `EAGAIN` received.

Or maybe is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at how the listener socket is added to the `epollfd`:

```
ev.events = EPOLLIN;       // this is the crucial bit
ev.data.fd = listen_sock;
```

It's not added in edge-triggered, it's added in level-triggered. So no need for a loop until `EAGAIN` on that one.

Comment: @Mat,if `listen_sock` is added to epollfd in ET mode(`|EPOLLET`),how will you deal with it? My above code is wrong,right?

Comment: the code in the man page is correct because it does _not_ set ET mode on the listener socket. If you add your listener in ET mode, then yes you need to take extra precautions and loop until EAGAIN. Be careful with starvation though.

Comment: @Mat,is the above code about `listen_sock` right quoted from the `man epoll` page?

Comment: pretty much. what you posted lacks some error checking and you've got a line that's pasted twice, but apart from that it's the same structure. Since you quoted that man page, I had assumed that you had the same setup code as in there.

Comment: @Mat,seems my man is outdated , `man, version 1.6d`,doesn't have that code about `listen_sock`.

Comment: [`man epoll`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man4/epoll.4.html). The man pages that are available on kernel.org are usually up to date.

Comment: @Mat ,will `LT` be much less efficient than `ET`?

Comment: There is no answer to that question, it depends on your specific workload.